# QML Profiler fails to connect to server

Tags: qt, qml, profiler

I'm trying to use QML Profiler to find out what is slowing my program down, but when I start it, I get this message:

> ```
> QML Profiler: Connecting to debug server at 127.0.0.1:50540 ...
> QML Profiler: Resolving host QML Profiler: Establishing network connection ...
> QML Profiler: Network connection dropped
> ```

which repeats for a few second, and eventually a popup appears saying:

> Could not connect to the in-process QML Profiler. Do you want to
>   retry?

I have checked **Enable QML Debugging and Profiling** in qmake build steps and rebuilt, and I also have **Enable QML** checked in Debugger Settings.

Comment: Did you figured it out? Having the same problem with QT Creator 3.5.1

Comment: Did you fix the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I met the same issue today when **remote device profiling**, it's caused by the qmlprofiler port was already been used.

I found the error message:
`QML Debugger: Unable to listen to port 10000`

then check port on my device:
`lsof -i :10000`, there indeed a process is using port 10000.

so I changed the qmlprofiler port to 10001 in below, the problem solved:

[image]