# How can I post a paint event with priority?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, paintevent

I'm having performance issues with a program I'm making using Qt. The problem stems from the large number of bitmaps I have updating every 16 ms; it takes about 300 ms to update them all. I'm not happy about this, but the bigger problem is the lag this creates in the rest of the UI. I would like to be able to reduce the priority of the updates so that the massive number of paintEvents don't block the event loop for the rest of the UI, but I'm having difficulty. Since `update()` and `repaint()` don't have a priority parameter, I tried using `QCoreApplication::postEvent()`, but it seems I'm not allowed to call paintEvent in this way because I get this error message:

```
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1
QPainter::setOpacity: Painter not active
QPainter::setFont: Painter not active
QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called
```

Here is the source of my problems, an array of 240 `QLabels` that I update all at once every 16 ms:

```
if (ui->objectSlotTabs->currentIndex() == 1) {
    for (int c = 0; c < 240; c++) {
        QEvent* event = new QEvent(QEvent::Paint);
        QCoreApplication::postEvent((*(ui->mArray))[c], event, -1);} }
```

EDIT: Here's an example image of what the program does and why the QLabels are so important (My program is the window on the left):

[image: example]

Comment: Also, I had to format the error message as code because it wouldn't let me post the question otherwise.

Comment: Are you posting events for labels which might not have changed?

Comment: No, I give them new data right before this.

Comment: It seems to me like you're trying to solve the wrong problem, the problem is you're trying to update 240 `QLabel`s...  Perhaps you should show us why you need all these `QLabels`?

Comment: That's basically the whole point of the program; I use it to get a real time update of 240 objects (represented by small bitmaps) in another process. Since the other process is a game that runs at 60 fps, I have to update all the QLabels at the same frequency.

Comment: So, the other process sends you the bitmaps?  How are the bitmaps arranged on screen - can you post a screenshot?

Comment: No, I load all the bitmaps I use to QPixmaps and scale them when the program starts up, so I thought it wouldn't be that resource intensive to paint them. It does make it a lot faster but lag is still a big issue. Also added screenshot of program btw.

Comment: Have you actually profiled it and know that the paint events are the actual problem? Are you sure you need to update the labels with every frame (I doubt the user can spot the changes that quickly), instead of every N frames?

Comment: i haven't been able to get QML Profiler to work (I actually posted about it a while ago but got no responses: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30200747/qml-profiler-fails-to-connect-to-server). However, when I don't run this update loop there's no lag at all, so I'm pretty sure this is the cause, especially since the QPixmaps already exist. I did try updating less frequently, but since all the updates are consecutive like this, it still lags briefly whenever the labels do update.

Comment: As you're not using QML here, the qml profiler wouldn't help anyway, I'd try http://www.codersnotes.com/sleepy

Comment: I ran it, not really sure how to interpret the results though... http://imgur.com/GYyHGa9

Answer (score 2):

There are two solutions (among many):

1. While you update the labels, disable the updates on the parent widget of the labels. Re-enable the updates when you're done updating the labels.
2. Use a `QGraphicsView` and place `QGraphicsPixmapItem`s within it, instead of labels.

Prioritizing the paint events won't help, since they are all for different widgets. If they were all for the same widget, then you wouldn't need to do anything, since the events are already coalesced and only one repaint for a given widget can ever exist in the event loop.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the benefit of (1); will that delay the updates until an appropriate time? As for (2), does QGraphicsView perform better? If so, I'll definitely make the switch. Also, the idea behind giving the updates a reduced priority was to hopefully allow other events, like clicking the checkboxes or pushbuttons, to jump ahead of the queued paintevents and allow the UI to at least run smoothly. Idk if my thinking is faulty there though.